# How do I round up to the decimal the second decimal?

Tags: python, rounding

I am having difficulty rounding numbers. I have tried including it in my initial descriptions i.e. `monthlyInterestrate = round(annualInterestrate/12.0, 2)`

and also in several formats when I print, i.e.:

```
print ('Minimum monthly payment: ' + str(round monthlyPayment),2)
```

Am I formulating this incorrectly?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
monthlyPayment = 10.126234
print ('Minimum monthly payment: ' + str(round(monthlyPayment, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "%0.2f"%monthlyPayment 
#or
print "{0:0.2f}".format(3.45678)
```

should work if your just trying to round it when you print although I should mention it does not always round quite right eg `3.3447 -> 3.34`  however `3.345 -> 3.35`

Comment: If you only need it for printing, prefer this. Though I would suggest `str.format` instead.

Comment: yeah i was adding that as you left the comment :P